# What is the difference between Direct Variation and a proportion?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, slope

So Both DV and a proportion can be represented as

$y = kx$

So I was wondering- is there a difference?

Comment: Please tag correctly...

Answer (score 1):

I believe that "*x* varies directly with *y*" means exactly the same as "*x* is directly proportional to *y*".

This is anecdotal, but it seems to be trendy in secondary math education these days to use the former terminology, although (as evidenced by the references on the wiki page for [Proportionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics))), the latter was used more 10 years ago. I don't know the reason for the change.